# Nuget Packages & Commands

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have been watching a few tutorial videos that use Nuget packages and during the videos the package console is somtimes used to type commands to make your project do wonderful things.

Great. But...

My question is where can I find a list of commands for a specific nuget package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet doesn't work like that. You run the same commands against a package.

See: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console